# How can I prevent the saving of incorrectly decrypted files?

Tags: encryption, vim, blowfish

When I enter the incorrect password for an encrypted file Vim displays gibberish.
If I accidentally save this file (*:wq* is muscle memory) I will lose the original content. How do I prevent the save of incorrectly decrypted files? Is it possible to set the 'readonly' option when the file is decrypted incorrectly?

Additional question -  Is it possible to recover the original content of the file after we have saved the incorrectly decrypted file?

PS - I was using `:se cm=blowfish2`

Comment: The bane of computer users, I messed up, overwrote something, how can I recover from my self inflicted pain!

Answer (score 2):

> How do I prevent the save of incorrectly decrypted files?

Adding the following map to `.vimrc` prevents mistakenly overwriting an encrypted file by asking the user if he/she really wants to quit:

```
au BufWinEnter * if &key!="" | cnoremap wq if input("Sure of quitting encrypted file? (yes or no)") == "yes"\|wq\|endif|endif
```

The important part here is the `&key!=""` comparison which evaluates to TRUE only if the file is encrypted.

> Is it possible to set the 'readonly' option when the file is decrypted incorrectly?

An incorrectly decrypted file will often display unusual characters. This can help to detect whether a file is incorrectly decrypted, like so `if search("[¶Éâ½]")!=0 | set readonly | endif`. This comparison evaluates to TRUE if any of the characters inside `"[]"` appear on the file.

> Is it possible to recover the original content of the file after we have saved the incorrectly decrypted file?

From `:help encrypt`

> WARNING: If you make a typo when entering the key and then write the file and exit, the text will be lost!